# Google Calendar API Push Notifications registered but not pushed

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-api-nodejs-client

I am using Nodejs client library to connect to the calendar's API.
I've followed the instructions here: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/push
and registered the domain that will get the notifications.
The following runs perfectly okay:

```
calendar.events.watch({
        auth: context.auth,
        calendarId: 'primary',//context.googleCalendarId,
        resource: {
            id: contextId,
            type: 'web_hook',
            address: 'https://xxxxxxxx.com/api/google-calendar/webhook',
            params: {
                ttl: '36000'
            }
        }
    }, function (err, webhookProperties) {})
```

which I get the following JSON:

```
{"kind":"api#channel","id":"56c9d4382bc6d42e8888888","resourceId":"vdVrqrQZDXIBrt288888888","resourceUri":"https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/48jhhtq888888888@group.calendar.google.com/events?alt=json","expiration":"1456634213000"}
```

However any modifications to the events on the calendar (add,update,delete) doesn't result any push back to my server.

Any thought of what am I missing?

THX

Comment: Do you mean the callback function is being called but the webhook specified in the `address` isn't?

Comment: Yap, that's exactly what I mean.

Comment: Do you have at least read-only access to the calendar id for the authenticated user?

Comment: Yap. I have both permissions (Read&Write)